# .htaccess Too Many Redirects (Combining 404 With Remove www)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Using .htaccess, I'm able to remove www from my site url or I'm able to handle 404 redirects for any nonexistent page on my site. However, if I try to have both, I get an error saying "too many redirects" and my site won't load anymore. How can I fix this so that I can both remove www and have 404 redirects without problems?

EDIT: My original post was already clearly not a duplicate.

.htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z.]+)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .? http://www.%1example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: @JonTirjan It's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the following set of rules a try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule . http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.)[a-z.]+)example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule . http://www.%1example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The redirect loop happens because you're redirecting your URLs to `http://www.%1example` domain irrespective of whether the `%1` group exists or not.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! It seems this part right here (?!www\.) basically told the code to function with or without www?